# Get bytes from HBITMAP

Tags: winapi, hbitmap

How can I get image bytes from hbitmap if I am given an HBITMAP pointer, and my application is console application. 
I tryed using GetDIBits which require such parameter as HDC, which I can't get.

EDIT:
I load bitmap from file:

```
HBITMAP bm = 0; 
BITMAP Bitmap;
bm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage (0, TEXT("C:\\img1.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

I pass the HBITMAP to the function and expect to get another HBITMAP of processed image:

```
HBITMAP out1 = func(bm);
```

Where func is:

```
HBITMAP func(HBITMAP im);
```

And the problem is how to get image bytes from HBITMAP.

Comment: Have you followed [Microsoft's Image Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145119%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) sample ?

Comment: @WhozCraig He stated that he tried `GetDIBits` but doesn't have a DC to pass to it (like the sample you linked to shows).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Forgive my failure to link using GetDIBits() to the OP trying (and failing) to following the prescribed method of doing this task from Microsoft's website. I didn't make the connection, and apparently I should have.

Comment: I guess the real question here, is "What are you planning on doing with the raw bytes?" If you want to write them to a PNG image, or something, you *need* to be getting device-independent data with GetDIBits.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart  I have to make some image processing and then output the result in a new HBITMAP pointer.

Comment: @maximus The question at the end my answer stands -- "where did you get an `HBITMAP` without an accompanying `HDC`?"

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart This is the specification of the function that I have to implement. I don't know where it comes from...

Comment: @maximus Well your question doesn't make any sense then. See my edit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart By the way, for testing purposes I am loading bitmap image using LoadImage function. And it comes without HDC

Comment: @maximus I think you need to show your code. I can help no further without seeing what you're doing / trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***See new answer since question was edited...***

You cannot do this without a handle to the device context (`HDC`). This is because [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879.aspx) expects an `HBITMAP` which is

> A handle to the bitmap. This must be a compatible bitmap (DDB).

A DDB is a [*Device-Dependent Bitmap*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183561.aspx), (as opposed to a DIB, or Device-Independent Bitmap). That means:

> Note that a DDB does not contain color values; instead, the colors are in a device-dependent format.

Which is why `GetDIBits` requires an `HDC`.  Otherwise it cannot get the color information.

Perhaps a good question is, where did you get an `HBITMAP` without an accompanying `HDC`?

---

If you're trying to create this bitmap in memory, first you can call [`CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489.aspx) to create an in-memory DC compatible with some device, then [CreateCompatibleBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488.aspx) with that DC. Then you have an `HBITMAP` and `HDC` to work with as you please. Otherwise, if you don't know what your `HBITMAP` is pointing to, you can't expect to do anything useful with it.

Comment: Do you mean that anyway if using HBITMAP pointer I will have to deal with HDC?

Comment: If you want to get color information, yes. Look at the link I included on DDBs.

Comment: Only if you are dealing with a **DDB**, which is dependant on an `HDC`. If you are dealing with a **DIB** instead, then you do not need an `HDC`. So what does your `HBITMAP` actually point to - a **DDB** or a **DIB**?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought an `HBITMAP` was always a **DDB**. [`HBITMAP` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) points you to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183377(v=vs.85).aspx) page, after which [About Bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162461(v=vs.85).aspx) states "**A bitmap is one of the GDI objects that can be selected into a device context (DC)**"

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart So it is not possible to connect existing HBITMAP with a newly created with HDC as you described in the Edit to your answer?

Comment: Like I said, (unless I'm wrong, @RemyLebeau?) an `HBITMAP` is already tied to an `HDC`, in the extent that the `HDC` has the color information that the `HBITMAP` is referring to. You can certainly try, but I don't expect it to work. Again, your `HBITMAP` has to be coming from *somewhere* - and most likely, that place has its `HDC`.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart if the HBITMAP was created using HDC, won't the GetDC function return the needed HDC if my function is called from DLL?

Comment: @maximus Did you look at the documentation for `GetDC`? It takes an `HWND` to a window. The `HBITMAP` you're getting from `LoadImage` has nothing to do with your window (if you even have one).

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart I mean in case if HBITMAP was retrieved not using LoadImage. What if I pass NULL to getdc or GetCompatibleDC. Are you sure it is impossible to do something if HDC not provided?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart OK I checked it, it is enough to call GetDC(NULL) and it works with it.

Comment: Like I've said, it all depends where the HBITMAP is coming from, and if it's a DDB or DIB. I've given you everything I know and then some.

Comment: If you load a bitmap from a resource, then you get an `HBITMAP`, but it's not tied to a particular DC. Like Remy has said, it is loading a DIB, not a DDB, so no DC is required.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is **not** to use `GetDIBits` (nor `GetBitmapBits`). These functions suck because they copy the data.
If you want the data directly, just use (for a DDB bitmap)

```
BITMAP bitmap;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), (LPVOID)&bitmap);
```

For a DIB bitmap use

```
DIBSECTION dib;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(dib), (LPVOID)&dib);
```

GetObject info, See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This will not involve any copying of data, thus avoids the complicated issues associated with GetDIBits, See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Esp. the comments at the bottom for an explanation of the difficulties with `GetDIBits`.

Note that you do **not** get the palette info, but since most bitmaps are 24 or 32 bits anyway this is hardly an issue most of the time.

Comment: According to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx if bitmap is not created by `CreateDIBSection`  `bitmap.bmBit` pointer will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx) to get the `HBITMAP`, then it is indeed a DIB (Device-Independent Bitmap) (they call it a DIBsection). However, you don't have the color information.

[This MSDN HOWTO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158898) shows you how to select the DIBsection into a memory DC.  They then go on to use `GetDIBColorTable` to get the palette. However, I believe from there, with that DC you can use [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879.aspx) to get the RGB bitmap information as you were trying to do.

Here's the general gist of it:

```
// Create a memory DC and select the DIBSection into it
hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );
(HBITMAP)SelectObject( hMemDC, hBitmap );

GetDIBits(hMemDC, hBitmap, ...);
```

You'll note in their code that `SelectObject` returns a handle to the what *was* in the DC. They then restore that before calling `DeleteDC`. I'm not sure its entirely necessary, but they do it. I left it out here for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for us is this: call `GetDIBits` while the correct palette (if indexed colour) is still selected into the device context. (Without the palette selected, the colours got garbled.)

But in our use case, it turned out that DIB sections performed a lot better, so check those out as well and benchmark. However, there are some gotchas. Windows wouldn't use the palette, we had to call `SetDIBColorTable` before use. But the device context still needed a one entry (black only) dummy palette selected **and realised** into the device context otherwise Windows would also ignore the palette set by `SetDIBColorTable`. Both `SetDIBColorTable` and `RealizePalette` needed to be present otherwise the colours would be garbled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try GetBitmapBits API even from console. More here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Just pass HBITMAP handle and you'll get your bytes

Comment: From MSDN: "'**Note**  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should use the [**GetDIBits**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879.aspx) function."

Comment: Furthermore, this is getting the raw bits, but it is *still* a device-dependent bitmap, so you don't have correct color information.

Comment: see my latest comment on the OP.

Comment: @Vahid Farahmand GetBitmapBits is returning 0. Which means fail.