# Read pixels (raw bytes) from an hbitmap without copying?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi, hbitmap

I have an `HBITMAP` handle to a device-dependent bitmap, resulting from this code:

```
// copy screen to bitmap
HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);//don't use hwnd, it doesn't work for non native windows
HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, w, h);
HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hScreen, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);
```

I want to access (read-only) the bits of the bitmap, read some values, do some calculations, then discard it.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674045/4822591), I shouldn't use `GetDIBits()` or `GetBitmapBits()` since they copy the data, but instead I should use:

```
BITMAP bitmap;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), (LPVOID)&bitmap);
```

But according to [`GetObject`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject):

> If `hgdiobj` is a handle to a bitmap created by calling `CreateDIBSection`, and the specified buffer is large enough, the `GetObject` function returns a `DIBSECTION` structure. In addition, the `bmBits` member of the `BITMAP` structure contained within the `DIBSECTION` will contain a pointer to the bitmap's bit values.
>
> If `hgdiobj` is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, `GetObject` returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the `GetDIBits` or `GetBitmapBits` function.

Which is pointed to in a comment on the above answer:

> According to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx if bitmap is not created by `CreateDIBSection` `bitmap.bmBit` pointer will be null.

So, is there anyway to access the bits of the bitmap (RGB values), without copying them?

If it helps, the device on which the bitmap is dependent is always a screen, so I guess it's always a 24bit or 32bit bitmap.

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/storing-an-image), regarding how to save an `HBITMAP` to a file, there's this section:

```
// Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure. (This structure  
// contains a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure and an array of RGBQUAD  
// data structures.)  

if (cClrBits < 24) pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1 << cClrBits));

// There is no RGBQUAD array for these formats: 24-bit-per-pixel or 32-bit-per-pixel 

else pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
```

So, I don't really understand what's happening here, and which is right?

Comment: I think the point is no.

Comment: You cannot access the raw pixel bits of a DDB without making a copy of the bits. You are stuck using `GetDIBits()`, sorry.

Comment: You already have the bitmap selected into a device context, so why don't you ask the device context to do the calculations (not that there's much to calculate). [`GetPixel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel) does that for you.

Comment: @IInspectable the area I want to read is probably 200x100 pixels, would using GetPixel be more efficient than copying it?

Answer (score 0):

> I shouldn't use `GetDIBits()` ... since they copy the data ...
> ...
> If it helps, the device on which the bitmap is dependent is always a screen, so I guess it's always a 24bit or 32bit bitmap.

Depending on the exact hardware that you use, pixels might be stored differently (maybe `Rr Gg Bb` on one computer and `Bb Gg Rr 00` on another one and `RG Br gb` on a third).

To ensure that you know the data format, you should use `GetDIBits()` because that function does not only copy the data but it also converts the data to a "known" format which does not depend on the hardware.

> would using `GetPixel()` be more efficient than copying it?

If you only want to inspect a few pixels (e.g. you want to know the color of 10 of the pixels), it should be more efficient.

If you are interested in all 20000 pixels, `GetDIBits()` should be more efficient.

> `pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO)LocalAlloc ...`
> So, I don't really understand what's happening here ...

`GetDIBits()` supports various bitmap formats, for example:

- "24-bit": This means 3 bytes per pixel (R, G, B)
- "256 color": One byte per pixel and a color map that contains the R, G, B definitions of each of the 256 colors

In the case of "24-bit", the `BITMAPINFO` structure consists only of a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure. I myself often write the code like this in this case:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER hdr;
...
GetDIBits(..., (BITMAPINFO *)&hdr, ...);
```

In the case of "256-color", the `BITMAPINFO` structure consists of a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure followed by 256 "R,G,B" tuples (the color map) - so the structure needs more memory compared to the "24-bit" case.

Please note that the bottom line of an image is stored first and there are padding bytes at the end of each line if the length of the line is not a multiple of 4 bytes.